# Instagram API call to retrieve authorization code with CURL returns empty

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

I am trying to set up an Instagram API feed with CURL in PHP, however the string returns empty when trying to retrieve the auth code, before later making a successful call to retrieve a user's content:

```
$uri = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/';

$data = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'response_type' => 'code'
];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
     var_dump($result);
```

However, when I access the URL directly in the browser, it does return to the redirect URI with the code that I need:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_HERE&response_type=code

i.e. the browser redirects successfully (including the "code" GET data) to http://REDIRECT_HERE/?code=XXXXXXXXXXXX

I'd basically like to store the auth code in a variable for later use rather than using the manual way of getting the code via a browser redirect.

Answer (score 1):

your browser sends the data in the url RFC-1738 style with a GET request, while your php curl code sends the data in a POST request encoded with `multipart/form-data`, no wonder the server gets confused. to send the data in the url with php just like your browser does, get rid of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` (because it tells curl to do a POST request instead of the default GET request, your browser does a GET request) and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` (because it tells curl to send it in the request body, while your browser send it in the url), and change your CURLOPT_URL to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri."?".http_build_query($data));
```

then your php curl request should roughly match your browser request, and get the same response. (there will still be minor differences, like a different User-Agent header, Accept header, and Accept-Encoding header, but that usually doesn't matter)

Comment: hi! thanks so much for your thorough answer. I have changed it accordingly, however still get an empty string returned ...?

Comment: @rainerbrunotte what do you get if you change it to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://dumpinput.ratma.net/?".http_build_query($data));
`  ?

Comment: string(152) "GET /?client_id=999999999999999999&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdumpinput.ratma.net&response_type=code HTTP/1.1 Host: dumpinput.ratma.net Accept: */* "

Comment: @rainerbrunotte that didn't help much. what do you get if you change it back to instagram and enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE? try  ```$tmp=tmpfile();curl_setopt_array($ch,[CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$tmp]); $result = curl_exec($ch);rewind($tmp);$result=stream_get_contents($tmp)."\n".$result;fclose($tmp);var_dump($result);``` , what do you get now?

Comment: wow, getting all kinds of stuff:  string(2945) "* Hostname was found in DNS cache * Trying 31.13.66.63... * Connected to api.instagram.com (31.13.66.63) port 443 (#2) * successfully set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: none CApath: /etc/ssl/certs * SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 * Server certificate: * subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.instagram.com * OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA * SSL certificate verify ok. > GET /oauth/authorize/?client_id=............etc etc etc

Comment: @rainerbrunotte if it's too much for a comment, use a pastebin (like fpaste.org ), that log may reveal why you're just getting an empty string

Comment: unfortunately the data returned does not include the necessary "code" (response_type) that I am looking for

Comment: @rainerbrunotte perhaps not, but may still contain the answer to why curl_exec returns an empty string, even tho you may not recognize it.